# Does $Mv$ converge to i.i.d in some sense?

Tags: pr.probability

I am not a professional mathematician so please excuse me if my question is not phrased correctly.

I am interested in the following simple sounding problem.

Consider a random $n$ by $n$ $0$-$1$ matrix $M$ where $M_{i,j} = 1$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ otherwise. Now choose a single random $0$-$1$ vector $v$ where $v_i=1$ with probability $1/2$. I can write down a precise formula for the probability distribution of $u=Mv$.  However, I would like to argue that for large $n$ the distribution of $u_i$ becomes very close (perhaps converges to in some sense) to i.i.d. $Bin(n,1/4)$.

My hand wavy intuition which might also reveal my motivation a bit more is that each $u_i$ is  tightly concentrated around its mean (as is the number of $1$s in $v$ and each row of $M$). Under these circumstances knowledge of $u_i$ tells you almost nothing about $v$ and hence almost nothing about other $u_j$. In other words the $u_i$ are in some sense very close to being independent with high probability.

Is there some way in which this can be formalized?

---

Here is an example of what I would like to do.  Say we have a set $S$ of $2^n$ $0$-$1$ vectors chosen i.u.d. and for each we compute the product $Y_i=MS_i$ (I have overloaded the notation as here $S_i$  and $Y_i$ refer to the $i$th vector not the $i$th element within  a vector). Let us make the matrix $M$ $m$ by $n$, that is potentially non-square, but still $0$-$1$ and each $M_{i,j}$ is i.u.d. as before.  I would like to work out the expected number of distinct $Y_i$ for large $n$ and $m$. The number of rows $m$ will typically be smaller than $n$ but not by too much.  I would like to be able to argue as if each element of $Y_i$ were independent to make the math easier. I only care about large $n,m$ approximations.

Comment: Are all the coefficients of $M$ and $v$ independent? Without some information about the **joint** law of the coefficients it is difficult to say much...

Comment: @UwF Yes they are all i.i.d.

Comment: There are several different questions here; one is "is each of the $u_i$ separately $Bin(n,1/4)$" (yes), another is "are the $u_i$ independent from each other?" (no, not always, I guess), and a third (if I read between the lines) is "does some result such as a LLN/CLT hold as if they were independent?". Maybe you should try and make the last one more explicit: what kind of properties do you need from them? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: It might help to note that, conditioned on the number of ones in $v$ (say there are $k$ of them), the $u_i$ are distributed i.i.d. $Bin(k,1/2)$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It is the third type of question I am interested in as you suggest. I will add a more specific example of how I would like to use this.

Comment: @usul Right so... my hand wavy thought was that conditioned on the number of ones being close to the mean, the $u_i$ might be distributed *almost* i.i.d. And give that they are almost always close to the mean maybe they are almost always *almost* i.i.d.

Comment: A. D. Barbour, L. Holst and S. Janson: Poisson Approximation. Oxford University Press 1992, 277 pp., ISBN 0-19-852235-5 should cover it

Comment: @guest In the spirit of http://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer, could you say a little (or a lot) more about this?

Comment: Calculate the probability that all the entries in $v$ equal $n/4$, in both models.  I get that they are very different.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay  You are right the probability seems higher for the $Mv$ case.  However my numerical experiments indicate that the expected number of distinct vectors (the motivation for the question) is very similar for large $n$ and $m$ so I am guessing this can't be the dominating factor. If you choose $2^n$ ($0$-$1$)-vectors $v$ i.i.d. then a constant fraction will be duplicated so I am in fact measuring the proportion of distinct vectors $v$ which have distinct $Mv$ for this case.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Is the right thing is to remove this question and ask one directly about counting the expected number of distinct $Mv$ at this point? I am not sure about MO etiquette.

Comment: Let $x$ be the difference between two random vectors $u$.  Find the probability that $Mx=0$ in both models.  This has direct bearing on how much duplication you will get.  I think you can keep this question for a while at least.

Comment: A. D. Barbour, L. Holst and S. Janson: The book uses (Charles) Stein's method to prove Poisson and Binomial distributional approximations for sums of dependent indicators. Generally the dependence is structured in their examples, just as the dependence is highly structured here. Without looking, I strongly suspect that one of their theorems will cover this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you are asking this:

What is the limit distribution as $n$ tends to infinity of $u=Mv$ for $M$ a uniform random $0-1$ matrix of size $n\times n$ and $v$ a uniform random vector of size $n\times 1$ ?

If you fix a coordinate $i$ and you ask for the distribution of $u^n_i$ is easy. $u^n_i\doteq\sum_{j=1}^n M_{i,j}v_j=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ where $X_j$ are i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X_j=0)=3/4$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_j=1)=1/4$ (i.e. is the sum of $n$ (1/4, 3/4)-Bernoulli random variables). Then $Z_i^n\doteq \sqrt{n}(u_i^n/n-1/4)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,(3/16)^2)$ as $n$ tends to infinity by the CLT.

About the independency...a simple calculation shows that the correlation between $Z^n_i$ and $Z^n_j$ for $i\neq j$ is $1/3.$ So there is no asymptotic independence even in this case.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am even more confused than I was now. What do we know about the expected number of distinct $Y_i$ in this case?

Comment: This question can be difficult.  It is not trivial to prove that as $n$ tends to infinity the matrix $M$ will become non invertible almost surely. So, if you fix a big $n$ and a matrix $M$ of size $n\times n,$ this just says that the probability of obtaining two $Y_i$'s equals is greater that the probability of having two $v_i$'s equals.

Comment: Your last question is very interesting and I am not able to answer it (I m far from that).

Comment: The observation about the probability of a matrix being non-invertible does tell you something about the square case but I am not sure what it tells you about the non-square case.

Comment: I cannot answer you precisely, but it is intuitive that the probability increases as the matrix is ``less square'', and it has a unique minimum at the square one. The extremes cases are easy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I miss something or have made a simple mistake, a direct computation shows that $Var(u_i)=3n/16$ and $Cov(u_i,u_j)=n/16$ for $i\ne j$. So $Corr(u_i,u_j)=1/3$ for $i\ne j$ no matter what $n$ is. So there is no asymptotic independence.

Yes, variance tends to zero, so there is concentration.

Comment: Thank you. I added a comment to @user39115's answer explaining my confusion.